# Iterate over each cell of a grid through whose interior a given line segment passes

Tags: computational-geometry, graphics

Let $a,b>0$ and suppose we have divided the domain $\Lambda:=[0,a]\times[0,b]$ into a grid of width $n_x$ and height $h_y$.

We enumerate the grid from bottom to top and left to right. Given $(x_0,y_0),(x,y)\in\Lambda$, I want to iterate over each grid cell through whose interior the line segment connecting $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x,y)$ passes.

Suppose we number the first cell by $(0, 0)$ and the last cell by $(n_x-1,n_y-1)$. How can we find an efficient algorithm, which iterates over the desired cells?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm), such as Bresenham's.